# Pinning in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, pinning

I am trying to do Pinning in my Ubuntu 16.04.

I am following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

But I cannot find `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu` file.
Do I have to make it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create it yourself, or put that line in:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf
```

that would do the work too.

*just for note:* files within `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` with `XX_some_name` will be looked at in order of their numbers, we use them to separate configurations from each other to be more organized, otherwise we can put all of them in: `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Comment: There isn't any apt.conf file in Xenial , just apt.conf.d.

Comment: @NidhiGupta you can make that yourself too, if you want.